# How to validate that an array is not empty in Mongoid?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongoid, activemodel, activesupport

```
class Foo
  include Mongoid::Document

  field :bars, type:Array
end
```

How to validate that the `bars` array is not empty?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the standard [**presence**](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#presence) validator:

```
class Foo
  include Mongoid::Document

  field :bars, type: Array

  validates :bars, presence: true
end
```

This works because the `presence` validator uses the `blank?` method to check the attribute during validation.

Comment: @BSeven You can always write your own validator that replicates `presence` (or inherits from it) and give it your own custom validator name. [Custom Validators](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#custom-validators) are explained and covered well in the the Rails Guides. Pay specific attention to the `ActiveModel::EachValidator` option.

Comment: @BSeven Also, arguably, `presence` is a perfect name.  Consider `Array#present?` in ActiveSupport.

Comment: @BSeven Why? Because `blank?`, `present?`, and `presence` methods are available on every single object in a Rails environment.  It's been this way for ~10 years and a definition for the word "present" is "existing" (aka non-blank or non-empty).

Comment: `present` sounds to me like not nil. Something like `unempty` would be more expressive. But I can see how `present` makes sense given the context of an array.